# If $f$ is absolutely continuous and $f'(x) = 0$ a.e., then $f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, absolute-continuity

> **Question**: Let $f$ be an absolutely continuous function on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ and that $f'(x)=0$ almost everywhere on $[a,b].$
>   Show that $f$ is a constant function.

My attempt:
Fix $x\in [a,b].$
We claim that $f(x)=f(a).$

Since $f$ is absolutely continuous, $f_{|[a,x]},$ restricted to interval $[a,x]$ is also absolutely continuous. 
Then 
$$\int_a^x f' = f(x)-f(a).$$
Since $f'(x)=0$ almost everywhere, so 
$$0 = \int_a^x f'.$$
Hence, 
$$f(x)=f(a).$$
Since $x\in [a,b]$ is arbitrary, therefore $f$ is a constant function with value $f(a).$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yeap , seems fine to me !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course this is trivial given the theorem that $f$ is the integral of $f'$. More interesting is proving it directly from the definition. **Hint** for that:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ as in the definition of "$f$ is absolutely continuous". Choose a compact set $K\subset[a,b]$ with $m([a,b]\setminus K)<\delta$, such that $f'=0$ at every point of $K$.

Now if $x\in K$ then $x\in(a,b)$ with $$|f(b)-f(a)|<\epsilon(b-a).$$

$K$ is  covered by finitely many such intervals. With a little finagling you can show that $K$ is covered by a finite  collection of disjoint such intervals, possibly closed or half-open. So $$\sum|f(b_j)-f(a_j)|<\epsilon\sum(b_j-a_j)\le\epsilon(b-a).$$

But $[a,b]\setminus\bigcup(a_j,b_j)$ is a finite union of intervals $[\alpha_k,\beta_k]$ with $\sum(\beta_k-\alpha_k)<\delta$;  hence the choice of $\delta$ shows that $$\sum|f(\beta_k)-f(\alpha_k)|<\epsilon.$$

Putting it all together, the triangle inequality shows that$$|f(b)-f(a)|<\epsilon(1+b-a).$$

Comment: Actually, the collection of those intervals which you use to cover $K$ forms a cover of $K$ in the sense of Vitali. And the "little finagling" can be justified by the Vitali Covering Theorem.